# Standard Token place - header or payload

Tags: security, spring-security, access-token

I want to secure my application using access token while communicating to the server.I am using nginx server which logs all the headers which are present in the request. It is a security threat if we are logging the header. If somebody can access the logs file. They can easily manipulate the data. Then why people use token in header?

In this case can we consider payload as the right choice?

What is the best place(or standard way) to put access token : Header or in payload?

What are the pros and cons of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, it is mainly a matter of taste, and of tools you use for testing ...

If you use *elaborated* tools, that allows you to set custom headers, header is nice, because it does not clutter the payload. But if you want to be able to test with a simple browser, if is easier to add a request parameter than a header ...

You can even accept both, first looking in the header, and then in payload if you could not find the token in header.

Comment: Thanks @Serge, I am using spring security and  by default Spring security adds token in header. So, is it good to write custom filter and then check in payload?

Comment: @DeepakKumar : I'm not aware that Spring Security has a token authentication solution out of the box with token in header, but if it has (or if you have) and it meets your requirements, just use it. It you need to pass it in payload, just use a custom filter (based on `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` in order to not reinvent everything). IMHO as I already said both ways are acceptable, and the best it the one that best fits in your use case ...

Comment: Thanks @Serge I am using nginx server which logs all the headers in the request. In this case can we consider that both are acceptable ?

Comment: @DeepakKumar Yes. If they meet your requirements, both are acceptable.

Comment: Thanks @Serge It is a security threat if we are logging the header. If somebody can access the logs file. They can easily manipulate the data. Then why people use token in header?

Comment: @DeepakKumar : if logs are unsecure in your context and if headers are logged, do not use headers and pass token in payload. For the security threat level, it depends on how much your logs are secured, how long they last, how long a token is valid, and if capturing a token can give access to other sensitive information. It also depends if requests are in HTTPS (crypted between client at nginx) or HTTP, clear text on the network. It is acceptable provided it meets your other requiements including security. **You** know them.